# Loopback 4 won't generate build files

Tags: node.js, ubuntu-16.04, loopbackjs, loopback4

When I try to build a Loopback 4 application with `npm run build` on Ubuntu 16.04, npm runs `lb-tsc` for 3 seconds and then just stops without printing any message. After it stops a `tsconfig.tsbuildinfo` file is generated but the `dist` folder is not.

My tsconfig.json is like the following:

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json.schemastore.org/tsconfig",
  "extends": "@loopback/build/config/tsconfig.common.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "dist",
    "rootDir": "src"
  },
  "include": ["src"]
}
```

I also tried running `npm run build:watch`, `npm run clean`, and running all of these with sudo and still no luck. Any idea what's causing this?

Comment: did you tried `npm run start`? does it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out the build files are actually generated but lb4 cli produces settings.json in .vscode folder which configures VS code to exclude the dist folder from project workspace by default.

Comment: didnt work for me, i tried the things like this --> ` "files.exclude": {
    "**/.DS_Store": true,
    "**/.git": true,
    "**/.hg": true,
    "**/.svn": true,
    "**/CVS": true,
    "dist": false,
  },`

Comment: It worked for me. I was just developing an extension component and linking it with main lb4 app with the help of npm link. When I build the extension folder vscode is hiding dist folder and npm link also not copying dist folder into node_module/linked_extension or package.

Answer (score 1):

Please try the following debugging steps:

1. Update to the latest Node.js LTS version (at the time of writing: v12.18.1)
2. Delete `node_modules`
3. Run `lb4 update`

   **^ Note: This will update the dependencies, which may contain breaking changes. Keep a backup of package.json**
4. Run `npm install`
5. Run `npm run clean`
6. Run `npm start`

Be sure to run the commands in the root directory of the project (where `package.json` is present).

Comment: This did not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove tsconfig.tsbuildinfo and relaunch the command

> npm run build